# Reflashing Session variable for AJAX call in Laravel (4.2)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session, laravel-4.2

We use Varnish (likely to  switch to Cloudflare) to cache the HTML of our pages. Occaisionally we would like to display a message to the user, which is flashed in the session: `Session::flash('user_message', 'You cannot perform that action');`.

The next page loads, and then there's an AJAX (to `/ajax/message`) call to check the server if there's a message to flash. Obviously the page load will absorb the flashed message, so what we've done in the BaseController is this:

```
if (Session::has('user_message') && !str_contains(Request::getPathInfo(), '/ajax/message')) {
   Session::flash('user_message');
}
```

Our AJAX call simply states:

```
$response = [];
if (Session::has('user_message')) {
  $response['user_message'] = Session::get('user_message');
}
return json_encode($response);
```

Which works, however, the next time a page loads, it will display the same message again! I've tried numerous things (such as Session::forget('user_message')) but to no avail.  I'm at my wit's end to solve what should be a really trivial task. Does anyone know of a better way to do this or what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your ajax call have any more code than that. For example a `die`? Also, are you sure that the base controller code is not running on the ajax response action?

Comment: There's no die, and the BaseController does run, however that's why I check if the path contains the URI of the AJAX call.